# Excel comparing two lists of string to return match

Tags: excel, string, list, compare, match

I have looked through google and found many similar questions but none of the suggested formulae really worked for me. I am trying to do something very simple: I am basically comparing two lists (list A and list B) of strings (namely genes) and having a third list (list C) that returns matches from list A to list B. The matches do not have to be exact in fact many aren't so I would need list C to return strings that have a partial or complete match from list A to list B (ex. List A's "EGF" is a match to list B's "EGFR", and return "EGF" in list C). Please help, I tried: if(iserror(search(list A's first string, entire list b),list a's first string, "") but it does not work. Please advise and thank you!!!!!!!!!!!

Example:

```
List A = HDGF PKNOX1 AGO1 ZFP64 WRNIP1 ARID4B SIN3A FEZF1 SIX2

List B = WNT5A RGS4 TUBA1A CLDN11 HDGFRP3 MSRB3 AKT3 SIX2
```

I'd like to compare list A's "HDGF" to every string i.e. "WNT5A", "RGS4" ... etc one by one to find a match (match does not have to be exact)

So "HDGF" would match with "HGDFRP3" since it is a substring of it so List C would return the matches

```
List C = HDGF SIX2
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the reply! List A would be [HDGF
PKNOX1
AGO1
ZFP64
WRNIP1
ARID4B
SIN3A
FEZF1
and list b would be WNT5A
RGS4
TUBA1A
CLDN11
HDGFRP3
MSRB3
AKT3
and if we compare them basically list a's first string "HDGF" to every string in list b one by one, list c should return "HDGF" since "HDGF" is a substring (or incomplete) match with "HDGFRP3" and the other ones should return blank since they dont match with anything, so list C would show "HDGF" in the end. Hope this helps! or anything pelase let me know

Comment: Please edit your original question so as to show your data in an easily readable format.  This kind of additional information is not really suitable for the comment format.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you so much for the replies. I've done that. I hope this is clearer. Please let me know!

Comment: To give you a handle on this, in order to conduct a comparison one needs to know the number of characters to determine a "match" and whether they have a particular position, such as at the start. For example, if a single character can determine a match than the comparison of HDGF with HPPP would result in an H in column C. If not, there should be a minimum to qualify. If a minimum of 2 characters qualify then HDGF and PPHG or HDGF and PGFP would still be matches for HG, respectively GF, if there is no rule for the matching characters' positions.

Comment: I see, in this case I'd want any string from list A to be a complete string for matching compared to list B for example "EGF" to "EGFR" not "EFG" or "EGFRR", list  A's string has to be a complete substring in alphabetical order but do not have to be the exact string when compared to strings in list B. I hope i make sense

Comment: How to deal with multiple matches then? So, EGF would be found in both EGFR and EGFRR. Should all matches be listed in column C? Comma-separated in one cell or in several cells below each other? How to handle the fact that EGFR, when its turn in the list arrives, is matching EGFRR? After you answer these questions the task will be clear. So we would return to the question of what have you done yourself? So far you have shown no own effort.

Comment: This is what I came up with and I think it worked: =LOOKUP(1E+100,SEARCH(N2,O:O),O:O) thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

*For your sample*, this seems to work:

```
=index(B:B,match(A1&"*",B:B,0))
```

but your question leaves open other possibilities.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've tried: =LOOKUP(1E+100,SEARCH(A1,B:B),B:B) and it worked too. Thank you so much for your help!